# I am getting an error in Kapt Debug Kotlin. I have update versions of dependencies in gradle file. still facing this issue

Tags: database, android-studio, android-room, dao, kapt

My app was running smoothly but I am getting this error now.I am getting an error in Kapt Debug Kotlin. I have update versions of dependencies in gradle file. still facing this issue. How it can be resolved? I saw somewhere to see your room database , dao and data class. still not able to figure out what is the issue.

[image]
The error is showing this file
[image]
**ROOM DATABASE**

```
@Database(entities = [Transaction::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class MoneyDatabase : RoomDatabase(){

    abstract fun transactionListDao():transactionDetailDao
    companion object {
        // Singleton prevents multiple instances of database opening at the
        // same time.
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: MoneyDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): MoneyDatabase {
            // if the INSTANCE is not null, then return it,
            // if it is, then create the database
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    MoneyDatabase::class.java,
                    "transaction_database"
                ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                // return instance
                instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**DAO**

```
@Dao
interface transactionDetailDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(transaction : Transaction)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(transaction : Transaction)

    @Update
    suspend fun update(transaction: Transaction)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM transaction_table ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun getalltransaction(): LiveData<List<Transaction>>
}
```

**DATA CLASS**

```
enum class Transaction_type(){
    Cash , debit , Credit
}
enum class Type(){
    Income, Expense
}
@Entity(tableName = "transaction_table")
data class Transaction(
    val name : String,
    val amount : Float,
    val day : Int,
    val month : Int,
    val year : Int,
    val comment: String,
    val datePicker: String,
    val transaction_type : String,
    val category : String,
    val recurring_from : String,
    val recurring_to : String
){
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id :Long=0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue is due to the use of an incorrect class being inadvertently used, a likely culprit being Transaction as that it also a Room class

Perhaps in **transactionDetailDao** (although it might be elsewhere)

See if you have `import androidx.room.Transaction`? (or any other imports with Transaction)?

If so delete or comment out the import

As an example with, and :-

[image]

And with the import commented out :-

[image]

Imported from github, had a play issue definitely appears to be with co-routines. commented out suspends in the Dao :-

```
@Dao
interface transactionDetailDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(transaction : Transaction)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(transaction : Transaction)

    @Update
    suspend fun update(transaction: Transaction)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM transaction_table ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun getalltransaction(): LiveData<List<Transaction>>
}
```

Compiled ok and ran and had a play e.g. :-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error is resolved. I was using the kotlin version 1.6.0. I reduced it to 1.4.32. As far as I understood, above(latest) version of Kotlin along with Room and coroutines doesn’t work well.